# Sudoku-net pseudo-solvable with minimum blocks

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku, number-theory

- A sudoku net is defined [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11780/sudoku-net-that-is-always-solvable).

> A sudoku net is defined as **'pseudo-solvable'** if we can deduce at least two valid 'not unique' solutions.

- friendly sudoku is defined [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12542/unsolvable-sudoku-net-with-maximum-blocks/12636?noredirect=1#comment39140_12636)

What is the sudoku net with the minimum possible blocks in such a way that this sudoku net is pseudo-solvable with at least one friendly sudoku?

---

**Challenge 2**

Find a sudoku net $N$ with visible set $V_N$ such that for any sudoku $S_1$, there is another $S_2\ne S_1$ where $V_N(S_1) = V_N(S_2)$ and $|V_N|$ is maximal.

---

**Bonus question**: (it is worth 50pts) is there any condition of pattern arrangements inside blanks which makes a sudoku unsolvable using previous result as work-domain?

Comment: Can you clarify the order of quantifiers? (Something like: FIND a net such that FOR ALL solved sudokus, if you place the net over the sudoku, then THERE EXISTS at least two solutions to the resulting puzzle)

Comment: @Lopsy in fact its not for all arrangements , there is specific oredering which would work it out

Comment: @Lopsy in that case such sudoko can be with 80 blocks so trivial for a question dont you think ?

Comment: @Lopsy does it look pleasant or encouraging now ?

Comment: Honestly I'm still not 100% sure what you mean, and I wouldn't want to work on a question like this one only to be told that I solved the wrong puzzle. Is your first question equivalent to "What's the smallest possible number of cells you can change to get from one solved Sudoku to a different solved Sudoku?"

Comment: For the second question, first we take the random sudoku, then build a net on it ), or do we have to build a net that works for any random sudoku?

Comment: the second net is laid above a solved sudoko

Comment: Yes, but can we look at the sudoku before building the net (I mean, to build a specific net for each kind of sudoku, as they aren't all the same)?

Comment: @leoll2 if you want to divide and rule all cases , im not advicing that as a solution , otherwise the solved-sudoko can be whatever still solved one when you put the net at the top.

Comment: @Ian MacDonald seems that your recent edit contradicts leoll2 's answer

Comment: @Agawa001 if that's how you feel, then maybe his answer is wrong. His answer to the question that I edited is "it depends on the sudoku", which is not answering an interesting question at all.

Comment: @IanMacDonald so i think i did just answer my own question without paying attention :/ , exept if someone would do better (not the condition part)

Answer (score 3):

## **MINIMUM BLOCKED BOXES:**

> $4$

O O **A**  | O O O  | **C** O O
O O O | O O O  | O O O
O O **B**  | O O O  | **D** O O
-------------------------------
O O O | O O O  | O O O
O O O | O O O  | O O O
O O O | O O O  | O O O
-------------------------------
O O O | O O O  | O O O
O O O | O O O  | O O O
O O O | O O O  | O O O

Where **A,B,C,D** are equal in pairs (the O are given numbers).
Suppose that both the *top-left* and the *top-right* squares are missing the numbers **5** and **7**. If you swap **A** with **B**, and **C** with **D** the sudoku will be still valid. This means that if you have clues about all cells except **A,B,C,D** there are 2 different valid solutions to the sudoku, which means **UNSOLVABLE**.

**Given a random solved sudoku, what's the minimal net that makes it pseudo-solvable?**
The answer is: it depends on the sudoku! Some particular sudoku need a net with just $4$ blocks, like the one showed in the picture, while other require up to $18$ blocks to become pseudo-solvable (put the blocks on all $1$ and $2$).
Example of the latter configuration is here:

> [image]

If you want a net that works for any sudoku, independently from the grid, just put the blocks on the first and second row. Anyway, this would still require $18$ blocks, not better than my previous solution.

## **When is a sudoku pseudo-solvable?**

When you don't have information about $4$ cells, arranged on a rectangular shape, such that $2$ of them belong to a quadrant, while the other $2$ belong to another quadrant (as shown in the above picture); also, the cells on the opposite vertices of the rectangle should contain the same values!

Let's say these values are $a$ and $b$ and the pattern is the same described in the above picture. The first row says the **A** and **C** must contain $a$ and $b$, but doesn't say in which order. Same for the third row, third column, seventh column, top-left box, top-right box.  This means, there are $2$ valid solutions for this sudoku.

## **When is a sudoku NOT pseudo-solvable?**

This means **solvable or impossible**! A Sudoku is impossible when it has internal contradictions (like two $7$ in the same row). When the sudoku isn't impossible (aka possible), it can be either solvable (admits 1 solution) or pseudo-solvable (admits 2+ solutions). How to tell them? First of all, given a grid, fill as many cells as possible using deductions. Now, if you have 4 unknown cells arranged in a rectangular pattern (see above for the other conditions), then the sudoku is pseudo-solvable!

Comment: this is correct for the first question .

Comment: @Agawa001 Added answer for the second, thinking about the bonus.

Comment: i changed the content btw , but your first intervention is still valid

Comment: leoll2 refering to your latest edit , do you mean the shortest [chain](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10769/maximize-chains-in-a-sudoku) ?

Comment: @Agawa001 my last edit is the answer to the 2nd question, I provided the minimum number of blocks in a net that transforms a solved sudoku into a pseudo-solvable one!

Comment: i know , but we can never know where is that chain ? henceforth you should case-separate your solution , which is very very hard and tiring

Comment: @Agawa001 I've just posted an example configuration where you'll never find the "rectangular pattern", so you can't make it pseudo-solvable with just 4 blocks. So far, the best way I found to make it pseudo-solvable is adding 18 blocks.

Comment: it depends on the shortest chain of the worst case grid...  so are you saying that you did just discovered a grid with 36 maximal chains !?

Answer (score 0):

my answer for the second question may be :

> # # # | # # # | # # #
>
> # # # | # # # | # # #
>
> ____  | ____  | ____
>
> ____  | ____  | ____
>
> ____  | ____  | ____
>
> ____  | ____  | ____
>
> ____  | ____  | ____
>
> ____   | ____  | ____
>
> ____  | ____  | ____

**18 blocks**

---

bonus question :

any logical relation isnt known yet but sure ... it would have something to do with graph-theory

Comment: That's 18 blocks, not 12.

Comment: fixed it ................

Comment: So, 18 blocks is the optimal net, as in my post?

Comment: dunno yet :S ... im waiting more initiatives